# APscheduler doesnt execute jobs when added from a wrapper function

Tags: python, regex, apscheduler

```
def print_hello(what):
 print 'Remind working'
 print what

def test(sender,kw):
  regex="remind me (to) (?P<reminder_text>.*?) (at|on|in) (?P<remind_time>.*)?"
  m=re.match(regex,kw['text'],re.DOTALL)
  if m:
    what=m.group("reminder_text")
    when=m.group("remind_time")
    when=nt.parse_natural_time(when)
    print when
    SCHEDULER.add_job(print_hello, 'date', name='testme', run_date=when,args=[what])
  SCHEDULER.print_jobs()`
```

The job gets added to the scheduler but the job doesn't run.

However when I execute this:

```
def print_hello(what):
  print 'Remind working'
  print what

def test(sender,kw):
regex="remind me (to) (?P<reminder_text>.*?) (at|on|in) (?P<remind_time>.*)?"
m=re.match(regex,kw['text'],re.DOTALL)
if m:
    what=m.group("reminder_text")
    when=m.group("remind_time")
    when=nt.parse_natural_time(when)
    print when   
SCHEDULER.print_jobs()

SCHEDULER.add_job(print_hello, 'date', name='testme', run_date=when,args=[what])`
```

The job is executed at that time instant.